# How to specify fonts on reactablefmtr themes

Tags: r, reactable

The code below is from Kyle Cuilla's page on themes https://kcuilla.github.io/reactablefmtr/articles/themes.html

In the displayed output on his page, it shows a nice sans serif font.  But when I run it, I get some kind of Times font.  I've looked through the docs and can't see where the default font is set (which I appreciate I may not have installed, but I'm pretty sure it was working before).

```
library(tidyverse)
remotes::install_github("kcuilla/reactablefmtr", force = TRUE)
library(reactablefmtr)
install.packages("viridis")
library(viridis)

data <- MASS::Cars93[1:20, c("Make", "Cylinders", "MPG.city", "Price")]
data %>%
  reactable(.,
            theme = slate(),
            defaultColDef =
              colDef(
                cell = data_bars(., fill_color = viridis::mako(5), text_position = "inside-end")
              )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One option would be the [`google_font`](https://kcuilla.github.io/reactablefmtr/reference/google_font.html) function which allows to apply a google font to your table:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(reactablefmtr)
#> Loading required package: reactable
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

data <- MASS::Cars93[1:20, c("Make", "Cylinders", "MPG.city", "Price")]
data %>%
  reactable(.,
            theme = slate(),
            defaultColDef =
              colDef(
                cell = data_bars(., fill_color = viridis::mako(5), text_position = "inside-end")
              )
  ) %>% 
  google_font(font_family = "Source Sans Pro")
```

[image]